# Configuring Cmake Command-Line

Tags: cmake

I'm new to using the Cmake command-line. Using the GUI I can specify a source directory and a build directory then generate. It works just fine.

When I run the command-line variant I don't get any output in the build directory.

```
 cmake -G "Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64" --build C:\MySource\Build C:\MySource
```

I also get other errors because it's trying to use Win32 yet I specify Win64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leave out the `--build` option. When you do the cmake configure step (equivalent to what happens by the cmake gui), you do not use `--build`. After you have generated the solution and projects you may build with `cmake --build . --config Debug`. (You can also specify which target to build with `--target MyTarget`.)

```
cd c:\MySource\Build
cmake -G "Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64" C:\MySource
cmake --build . --config Debug
```

For the configure step (with the -G option), you may use a relative directory `..` rather than the absolute path--either way is fine.

Comment: How can I specify where I want the generated solution files to be?